# Scss/Sass webpack/project set up not working

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack

New to setting up webpack. Trying to set up a very simple html/css/js site, no react or other js framework. I am trying to add scss right now and keep getting this error.

```
ERROR in ./src/main.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'style-loader' in '/Users/brian/Documents/Hiromi/6_WebFiles'
 @ ./src/main.js 1:0-32
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./src/main.js
```

Here is my webpack config:

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.js',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "html-loader",
            options: { minimize: true }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader"]
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: 
        [{
          loader: "style-loader"
        }, {
          loader: "css-loader"
        }, {
          loader: "sass-loader",
          options: {
            includePaths: ["./src/*"]
          }
        }]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: "./src/index.html",
      filename: "./index.html"
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "[name].css",
      chunkFilename: "[id].css"
    })
  ]
};
```

All I want to happen is for webpack to compile the ./src/main.scss file to to ./dist/main.css file.

Have tried a bunch of stuff, but not sure how to make this happen. Any hints would be amazing!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For every loader you want webpack to use, you'll have to download it via npm or yarn so that webpack can then find it in your `node_modules` directory.

So you will need to install `style-loader`, but also `sass-loader`, `css-loader`, `html-loader` and `babel-loader` via npm.

`babel-loader` in turn also needs `babel-core` to run, so you'll need to install that too

You can do this by running:

```
npm install --save style-loader sass-loader css-loader html-loader babel-loader babel-core
```

If you already have any of these modules installed, npm will ignore it, so the entire string should be safe to run

Comment: Thank you so much @Anuj!! Can't believe that that was all I was missing!